# create_string_buffer throwing error TypeError: str/bytes expected instead of str instance

Tags: python, string, pointers, ctypes

I am trying this simple ctypes example and getting the error mentioned

```
>>> from ctypes import create_string_buffer
>>> str = create_string_buffer("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 59, in create_string_buffer
buf.value = init
TypeError: str/bytes expected instead of str instance
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

On the same note, I am trying to pass a pointer to a string to a C function from my python code so that I can perform some string operation there and return another string. Can someone give me some sample code on how to do that?

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char * echo(char* c)
{
      // do stuff
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever assign to `str` (not that that's the problem here). Shadowing builtins is evil.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With regards to getting it working, if you pass it a `bytes` object, it works:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'hello')
<ctypes.c_char_Array_6 object at 0x25258c0>
```

Looking at the code for `create_string_buffer`:

```
def create_string_buffer(init, size=None):
    """create_string_buffer(aBytes) -> character array
    create_string_buffer(anInteger) -> character array
    create_string_buffer(aString, anInteger) -> character array
    """
    if isinstance(init, (str, bytes)):
        if size is None:
            size = len(init)+1
        buftype = c_char * size
        buf = buftype()
        buf.value = init
        return buf
    elif isinstance(init, int):
        buftype = c_char * init
        buf = buftype()
        return buf
    raise TypeError(init)
```

Doing it directly,

```
>>> (ctypes.c_char * 10)().value = b'123456789'
```

This works fine.

```
>>> (ctypes.c_char * 10)().value = '123456789'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: str/bytes expected instead of str instance
```

This shows that same behaviour. Looks to me as though you've found a bug.

Time to visit http://bugs.python.org. There are a few bugs related to `c_char` and `create_string_buffer` which are in the same field, but none reporting that giving it a `str` now fails (but there are definite examples showing it used to work in Py3K).

Comment: Thanks for the solution with passing as bytes object. Could you please answer the later part of the question? How can I print the string value returned as a pointer from that C method in python?

Comment: @Helali: I don't know. I haven't ever dealt with C code in Python. If you have a `ctypes.c_char_Array_*` instance it's just `thingy.value`, but I presume that's not your question.

Comment: @eryksun: I don't care about that; `c_char` arrays *used* to accept `str`, and still claims to but doesn't any more. Thus it is a regression. Whether they choose to change the documented behaviour rather than fix the regression is their choice. But it is a bug.

Answer (score 15):

You're using Python 3, and strings (`str`-type) in Python 3 are Unicode objects.  `create_string_buffer` creates C `char` arrays, so you are required to pass a `bytes` object.  If you have a `str` object encode with an appropriate encoding to create a `bytes` object.  Note there is a `create_unicode_buffer` that creates C `wchar` arrays as well and takes Python 3 `str` objects.

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 21:51:15) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.create_unicode_buffer('abcd')
<ctypes.c_wchar_Array_5 object at 0x00C2D300>
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'abcd')
<ctypes.c_char_Array_5 object at 0x00C2D1C0>
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer('abcd'.encode('utf-8'))
<ctypes.c_char_Array_5 object at 0x00C2D300>
```

In regards to the 2nd part of your question, do you want to edit the existing string or return an entirely new string allocated on the heap?  If the former, use `create_string_buffer` to pass a mutable string to the function, then modifying it in place will work.  Here's a simple example calling _strupr() from the Windows MSVCRT library:

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 21:51:15) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> c = ctypes.CDLL('msvcr90.dll')
>>> strupr = c._strupr
>>> a=ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'abc')
>>> strupr.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
>>> strupr(a)
b'ABC'
```

Note setting the `restype` (result type) of the function to a `c_char_p` tells ctypes to convert the return value to a `bytes` object.  Also note that `_strupr` converts a string in place, so a mutable string buffer must be passed.  Only pass Python byte strings to C functions that take `const char*`, since modifying Python strings directly via ctypes is **Bad<sup>TM</sup>**.

Comment: Does `ctypes.create_unicode_buffer('abcd')` work for you? It isn't working for me on Python 3.2 (not 3.2.1 which I see you have) on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit, and it clearly isn't working for @Helali.

Comment: Yes, it works for me.  I looked in the release notes for 3.2.1 and don't see requiring `bytes` for `create_string_buffer` as a fix, but I did find this issue (http://bugs.python.org/issue8306) saying `str` to `bytes` implicit conversions should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is the size of the buffer required for the string, so pass it the length the buffer should be. It will create a char array of that size.

```
>>> from ctypes import create_string_buffer
>>> buf = create_string_buffer(20)
>>> buf
<ctypes.c_char_Array_20 object at 0x355348>
>>>
```

Comment: Well I got that. But how do I initialize that buffer to a string value? And finally how can I pass that to the C method? Thanks.