# Ctypes create_string_buffer gives raise TypeError(init)

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to pass a Python string to a c function (DLL) using ctypes. The function needs a const char*. I am using create_string_buffer, but it returns an error:
raise TypeError(init)
TypeError:

My python code is quite simple:

```
testUpdate = myDll['testUpdate']
def testUpdate(Path):
    p_path = ctypes.create_string_buffer(Path)
    print ctypes.sizeof(p_path), repr(p_path.raw)
    print repr(p_path.value)

    testUpdate(p_path)
    testUpdate.restype = ctypes.c_char
```

And my C code is even simpler:

```
char testUpdate(const char* softwareToolsPath){
     char p;
     p = *softwareToolsPath;
     return p;

}
```

I saw this post:
[create_string_buffer throwing error TypeError: str/bytes expected instead of str instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237133/create-string-buffer-throwing-error-typeerror-str-bytes-expected-instead-of-str)
But it didn't help. Could anybody help?

I am using python 2.7.

To avoid any confusion, all I'm trying to do is give a Path (using Python) to a DLL. That DLL will open the file pointed by the path and do its magic. So I am simply trying to write a little wrapper for a existing C function.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, the argument is a valid str. So, that is not the problem :)

Comment: I'm not sure to see what information this method can give, other than what I already know. The error that I got pointed me to that file. I looked before, but I can't figure out the problem. As for comparing the output to the original. the output gives me : <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_27'>.  Am I missing something? (by the way thanks for your help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused. Is `testUpdate(p_path)` supposed to call a C function? It looks like it recursively calls the python code (with the wrong parameter type). Try to rename the Python function.

BTW, Your C code is faulty. I suppose what you want is

```
char * testUpdate(const char * softwareToolsPath) {
    char * p;
    p = softwareToolsPath;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that it looks like it recursively calls the python code? I am kind of new to Python... I might not be doing what I think I'm doing.

Comment: You have a symbol `testUpdate`, initialized to something from a DLL. Then you reuse this name by `def testUpdate()`, which overwrites the original definition. By the time of a call at line 7, only the latter is visible.

Comment: Well, I think I need 'create_string_buffer', because this is only a test on simpler C code. I will need to modify the string. So if I need to modify the string I need it. From what I read.

Comment: To both of you, thanks you very much. Your comments showed me my mistakes. I think the important part of the answer was the recursive calls. That with your explanations helped me solve my problem. I changed my code based on the comments and it works.