# How to initialize a string array for multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Here is sample code of Sharing state between processes

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

The output is

```
3.1415927
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

I want to initialize a list with string elements instead of integer elements.  Then I want to assign the list specific string elements.  My code is the following.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(a):
    a = ["up", "down", "left"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array('b', [])

    p = Process(target=f, args=(arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(arr[:])
```

I want the output to be

```
["up", "down", "left"]
```

But instead I get the output

```
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
[]
```

Comment: I fixed the Type Error, but the main part of my question is still unanswered.  I still receive an empty list as my output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a tuple of args, you need to add a trailing comma to create a tuple:

```
 p = Process(target=f, args=(arr,)) # <- trailing comma
```

Or use tuple explicitly:

```
 args=tuple([arr]))
```

The comma creates the tuple not the parens.

No idea how multiprocessing will help but to get the output you want:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
from ctypes import c_char_p
def f(a):
    a[:] = ["up", "down", "left"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array(c_char_p, 3)
    p = Process(target=f, args=(arr,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(arr[:])
['up', 'down', 'left']
```

The first arg to Array is the type which we need to use `ctypes.c_char_p` as we are adding strings, the second arg is the size of the array i.e 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the tuple error, but I am still not getting my desired output.  I still receive the empty list [ ].  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @SagwaTheCat, that is completely different to your original question but obviously you get an empty list as your function does nothing and arr is an empty array so you get an empty array, what else would you expect?

Comment: It was my understanding that if I use arr as a parameter in the function f then arr would be set to the array ["up", "down", "left"].  Is this not correct?

Comment: nope, a is a local variable in the scope of the function, the a you pass in is never used or changed, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted the array arr to be equal to ["up", "down", "left"] after it is passed through the function f as a parameter.

Comment: I don't see how multiprocessing fits into the logic at all

Comment: If I am able to do this than I will be able to perform my actual task.

Comment: How you do It completely depends on the task, I added some code but without some context it is hard to give a more useful example

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am getting the following output now `TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
[None, None, None]`

Comment: Ah ok, just saw you are using python3, to work as is you would need to pass bytes `[b"up", b"down", b"left"]`,  an explanation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237133/create-string-buffer-throwing-error-typeerror-str-bytes-expected-instead-of-str, are you actually using strings?

Comment: Yes, I am using strings.  After using `[b"up", b"down", b"left"]` I got the the error `ValueError: invalid string pointer` which I am trying to fix.  Thanks

Comment: changing to bytes and using the code above should output `[b'up', b'down', b'left']`

Comment: That's odd, probably something wrong with my code.  I'll try to fix this.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: i guess the array has to be decoded from binary to string:
`for item in arr:
        print(item.decode('UTF-8'))`

Answer (score 3):

Process expects `args` to be a tuple, instead you just pass `arr`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

> **args** is the argument tuple for the target invocation.

```
a = (arr)
print(type(a))
# Output: <class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.SynchronizedArray'>

a = (arr,)
print(type(a))
# Output: <type 'tuple'>
```

This fixes your problem:

```
p = Process(target=f, args=(arr,))  # notice the , after arr
```

Comment: Pretty the same, but obviously we wrote the answer simultaneously? We answered almost at the same time.